# Opening video player from android webview and not opening it on a regular <a>

Tags: java, android, video

I'm trying to make an app which opens up a website, the website itself has videos (mp4, 3gp, etc) aswell as regular `<a>` tags.

```
final class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".mp4")) {
            Intent vIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            vIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/mp4");
            view.getContext().startActivity(vIntent);  
            return true;
        } else {
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }
}
```

The code i'm using to find an  click, is the above, and it basically works for regular links, but when I click an mp4, for example, nothing happens.

If I take off the IF... Else statement, then the mp4 plays just fine, Any suggestions on what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if (url.matches(".*.mp4"))
{
    mpla mpla
}
```

I have an issue though with the code. In android 2.1 and older it works and opens a youtube player, and playes the video. but from 2.3 and above it just does nothing. I debugged it and found out that when clicking on the video the shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not called!